# Insert player name with new high score

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-input

I'm creating a game with a scoring system, but at the moment the players' names are not included with their high score. The idea is that the player is able to add their name once the game over screen appears and provided they have achieved a new high score.

Initially the system would only save one high score, but now 5 high scores are saved which will be called within a table elsewhere, which is where I would also like the player name to be displayed.

I'm not that familiar with C# so do not know how to incorporate this sort of user input, so I'm happy to hear the available options.

This is my code for the score system:

```
public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public Text scoreText;
public Text hiScoreText;
public Text gameOverScoreText;

public float scoreCount;
public float hiScoreCount;

public float distance;

public float pointsPerSecond;

public bool scoreIncreasing;

//create array for last 5 high scores
float[] highScores = new float[5];

//create list for scores
public List<float> ScoreHistory;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    //if there is a high score, the game will register it, otherwise it will be 0 - this is for one score
    /*if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("HighScore"))
    {
        hiScoreCount = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore");
    }*/

    //obtain last 5 scores
    ScoreHistory = LoadScoresFromPlayerPrefs(5);

    // Set the current high score to be the highest score in the player history - if there is no high score saved, high score will be 0
    if (ScoreHistory.Count > 0)
    {
        hiScoreCount = ScoreHistory[0];
    }
    else
    {
        hiScoreCount = 0;
    }

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (scoreIncreasing)
    {
        //adding points every frame/update => but shows decimals
        scoreCount += pointsPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
        //scoreCount += Vector3.Distance(transform.position, camera.position);
      
    }

    if(scoreCount > hiScoreCount)
    {
        hiScoreCount = scoreCount;           

        //saves value called high score and the hiScoreCount value - not used if saving more than one score
        //PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighScore", hiScoreCount);
    }

    //adding text to score
    //Mathf.Round rounds scoreCount and hiScoreCount to nearest whole
    scoreText.text = "Score: " + Mathf.Round(scoreCount);

    hiScoreText.text = "High Score: " + Mathf.Round(hiScoreCount);

    gameOverScoreText.text = "Your Score: " + Mathf.Round(scoreCount);

}

//function which needs a number value to take in - can be used more than once
public void AddScore(int pointsToAdd)
{
    //adding points to score
    scoreCount += pointsToAdd;

}

// Save the current score to the list of scores, and then write them to the player prefs
public void SaveCurrentScore()
{
    ScoreHistory.Add(scoreCount);
    //put scores in order
    ScoreHistory.Sort();

    
    for (int i = 0; i< ScoreHistory.Count; i++)
    {

        //key is the name of the value being stored
        var key = "High Score " + i;

        //value is what is being stored (i.e. the high scores) => ScoreHistory is being used as each score is being saved
        var value = ScoreHistory[i];

        //high scores are being saved using PlayerPrefs
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(key, value);
      
    }
    
}

// Loads the scores from the player prefs and returns them in a list of floats
private List<float> LoadScoresFromPlayerPrefs(int maximumNumberOfScoresToLoad)
{
    //no visibility modifiers - this is a local variable
    List<float> LoadScores = new List<float>();

    //loop will run once per score
    for (int i = 0; i < maximumNumberOfScoresToLoad; i++)
    {

        //key is the name of the value being stored
        var key = "High Scores " + i;

        //will return value of the key if there is one, otherwise will return default value of 0.0
        //PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(key);

        var score = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(key);
        LoadScores.Add(score);
    }

    return LoadScores;
 }
}
```

Comment: You need a player class so you can keep each  player separate.  The player class needs the name and the list of scores.  Then you need a List<Player> and add all the players to the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to enter a name you'll either have to use

1. Unity's UI system (e.g. [input field](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-InputField.html)) or
2. code something yourself (e.g. observing [Input.inputString](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-inputString.html) after finish), which I would only recommend if you have something like old arcades, allowing only 3 characters.

In both cases you need to be able to detect the end of your user's input with a detectable submit (e.g. return key, or a dedicated UI button). Afterwards you can just store it with the respective points.

To bind the points and name together just add a struct containing both

```
public struct ScoreData {
    public float Score { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and use it for your `ScoreHistory`

```
public List<ScoreData> ScoreHistory;
private string playerName; // store the name input by player here
...
public void SaveCurrentScore()
{
    ScoreHistory.Add(new ScoreData { Score = scoreCount, Name = playerName });
    //put scores in order
    ScoreHistory = ScoreHistory.OrderBy(s => s.Score).ToList();


    for (int i = 0; i < ScoreHistory.Count; i++)
    {

        //key is the name of the value being stored
        var scoreKey = "High Score " + i;
        var nameKey = "High Score Playername " + i;

        //value is what is being stored (i.e. the high scores) => ScoreHistory is being used as each score is being saved
        var value = ScoreHistory[i];

        //high scores are being saved using PlayerPrefs
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(scoreKey, value.Score);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(nameKey, value.Name);

    }

}
```

Comment: Why not just add them to the PlayerPrefs using [PlayerPrefs.SetString(...)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.SetString.html), just as you do with the score?

Comment: Ok so I now have something where the score can only be saved if the player submits their score by typing in their name. However, the new name replaces the previous name on the score table. Is there a way to prevent the previous data being overwritten, or do I have to submit a score and name differently?

Comment: Since you only want to save the top 5 scores why does overwriting previous data bother you?

Comment: It's not that, it's the name of the player that's being overwritten that bothers me. Say player one submits a score, then player two plays the game on the same device and submits their score; even though player one submitted their own name and score, player two's name will overwrite theirs, making it look as though they also achieved player one's score. That's what I'm wanting to avoid.

Comment: Do you want to store 5 scores per player (so that each player can track their own skills improving)? Or do you want to store a list of 5 scores with the possibility of 5 different players having achieved them (so that the current player compares his skill to other players')?

Comment: The latter would be preferable. I'm going to be working on a list similar to what I have with the scores, unless that's not required for this?

Comment: I updated my answer to illustrate a way to couple the name and the achieved score for saving. You'll have to update your loading for this as well, but that is straight forward.